# Confirm phone changed code in Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a Confirmed user in Cognito, and I am changing the phone number using AminUpdateUserAttributes. This action triggers a confirmation code sent to the new phone number to verify it. The problem is that I can't find a method in the [API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUpdateUserAttributes.html) for confirming this code. Trying confirmSignUp throws this exception:

```
"error_message": "Invalid code provided, please request a code again. (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ExpiredCodeException; Request ID: 98dd9ed0-f96b-4e24-ab19-f3258e1c1e4e; Proxy: null)",
```

I think it is because the user is not signing up, but changing their phone number. So, which would be the way for confirming the phone number attribute change using the code sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching deeper I found this method in aws doc, that solves my problem:

**VerifyUserAttribute**

Verifies the specified user attributes in the user pool.

Request Syntax

```
{
   "AccessToken": "string",
   "AttributeName": "string",
   "Code": "string"
}
```

So I tested this and successfully verified the user's phone change, as also pointed out in cognito dashboard user's description:

[image]